# What's the command to make Caps Lock key back as the Caps Lock key

Tags: 18.04, keyboard

I always make caps lock as an additional <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key using:

1. adding `XKBOPTIONS="ctrl:nocaps"` in `/etc/default/keyboard;` and then
2. `$ setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps`

If the above command makes <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, what's the command to make it back as <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to `man xkeyboard-config`

```
   Ctrl position

       ┌────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
       │Option                     Description                                                  │
       ├────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
       │ctrl:nocaps                Caps Lock as Ctrl
```

So you can simply use the command `setxkbmap -option ctrl:nocaps` to make Caps Lock as Ctrl.

To make the Caps Lock to behaviour as Caps Lock just remove the option `ctrl:nocaps` and run simply `setxkbmap -option` this means there are no options specified.

In Somecases, you may have more values for `setxkbmap -option`.. You must be careful to run the command `setxkbmap -option` i.e with empty options.

So before running with empty options, first check what are the options configured with the command `setxkbmap -v 10`

Example output:

```
$ setxkbmap -v 10
Setting verbose level to 10
locale is C
Trying to load rules file ./rules/evdev...
Trying to load rules file /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/evdev...
Success.
Applied rules from evdev:
rules:      evdev
model:      pc105
layout:     us,us
variant:    ,
options:    ctrl:nocaps,lv3:lalt_switch,grp:sclk_toggle
Trying to build keymap using the following components:
keycodes:   evdev+aliases(qwerty)
types:      complete
compat:     complete
symbols:    pc+us+us:2+inet(evdev)+group(sclk_toggle)+level3(lalt_switch)+ctrl(nocaps)
geometry:   pc(pc105)
$
```

If you observe the line starting with options:
I have 3 options configured.. so to keep the other options as it is and to remove the option `ctrl:nocaps` I have to run

`setxkbmap -option lv3:lalt_switch,grp:sclk_toggle`

In your case: since you have edited `/etc/default/keyboard` file to include XKBOPTIONS, you must remove the option "ctrl:nocaps" from this file also.